# Mysql - Money transfer: Transfer data from one field to another in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to simulate a money transfer from one account to another. The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
(ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 Password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 Dollars double,
 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

I can't figure out a statement in MySql to transfer data from one cell/field (dollars) to another. It has to add the transferred amount to the cell and withdraw the same amount from the cell the transfer is made from.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement will update the dollar column column for both deposits and withdraws.  To see it in action, take a look at this [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa1f1/1/0).  In the example below $150 is transferred from Bob's account to Sara's.

```
Set @TransferAmount = 150;
update new_table withdraw, new_table deposit
set withdraw.Dollars = withdraw.Dollars - @TransferAmount,
    deposit.Dollars = deposit.Dollars + @TransferAmount
Where withdraw.name = 'Bob Smith' and deposit.name = 'Sara Hampton';
```

Comment: Hi @tobias_jac if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You nay want to simply select and update and do these operations in one transaction. As you did not provide any information about what framework/library you use, I am not able to tell you how exactly...

```
But what you need is
    SET @payers_money= select dollars from new_table where Name = 'Name of paying person';
    SET @receivers_money=select dollars from new_table where Name = 'Name of receiving person';
    SET @payment=10; -- for example
SET @payers_money=@payers_money-@payment;
SET @receivers_money=@payers_money+@payment;
    update new_table SET dollars =@payers_money where name= 'Name of paying person';
    update new_table SET dollars = @receivers_money where name= 'Name of person being paid';
```